# Git Flow - Cherry Pick vs CI

Tags: git, git-flow, branching-strategy

I am searching for better workflow to use with Git. I found `git-flow` very useful workflow which fits in enterprise product based solution.

The most useful functionality I like is of Cherry-Pick. Currently we are using SVN and it is bottleneck for us to release version timely, because all the development happens in single branch version and trying to release that version when all the features got completed. Using git-flow, we can simply avoid such bottleneck and have full control over release cycle.

However, The problem I face is CI. In CI, all your features got merged into single branch and follow appropriate workflow to give feedback. 
Second is, out Business Analyst want to test all the features and want to provide feedback based on that. In current scenario it is not feasible because we are not merging to `develop` branch until feature is completed.

**Is there any solution to fill requirement of Cherry-pick with CI and BA in Git-flow?**

Toggle is one solution, however I am not clear how toggling can work with major changes in relational database. Old functionality will be broken in that case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By CI- you should mean Continuous Integration right? Not sure how that fits in version management system,

Comment: Yes, Continuous Integration. As per CI, all changes should integrate at one place (branch) and need to run Unit and Integration test with all the features. That is going to give you exact feedback of all the existing features and how they are going to integrate into product.

Comment: Ideally , all your feature branches should create a pull request to your develop branch(not release) everyday whenever owner of the feature branch feels the code wont break. Your Integration and Unit test Cases should run from this develop branch daily using some kind of automation like Jenkins.

Comment: If I daily merge features to develop branch then long running features may interrupt release.

Comment: You have have long running features and still you expect CI running daily , that kind of is contradictory in itself .